# TFS - Allow user to undo checkouts

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to allow a user to undo the checkout of another user without giving them the full administrator role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a group of users (such as the contributors group) then you can simply update the permissions of the group.

Go to the root of the team project in Source Control Explorer, right click and select "Security" from the context menu. In the window that appears select your contributors group in the top panel and then scroll down to "Undo other users' changes" and slect the "allow" check box.
[image: Tfs Source Control Permissions]

If you want to limit the users who can do this then create a new TFS group.

Comment: Thank you, my confusion came from right hand clicking the TFS project in the team explorer rather than the source control explorer. You are shown a different list of permissions if you go through that route and click on security.

Comment: I've been bitten by that one in the past as well. You just need to think of the Project settings as permissions for server operations like work items and builds and the settings in Source Control explorer as "File System" permissions.